# How can I remove extraspace in listview bottom?

Tags: android, listview

My xml view for layout_through.axml is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultsTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dual_listview_header_results"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Results"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewtextsizeCommon"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewPaddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewPaddingTopBottom" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/dual_listview_header_numberofframes">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noofframeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/PortscustomviewnoofframeTextViewMarginTop"
            android:text="Number of Frames"
            android:textSize="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewtextsizeCommon"
            android:textColor="@color/BlackText" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noofframeTextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/PortscustomviewnoofframeTextViewMarginTop"
            android:text="Received of Each Size"
            android:textSize="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewtextsizeCommon"
            android:textColor="@color/BlackText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/loopbackThroughListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear_2"
    android:divider="#0188dd00"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/PortsloopbackThroughListViewPaddingLeftRight"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/PortsloopbackThroughListViewPaddingLeftRight"
    android:background="@color/DarkGrey" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/loopbackThroughListView"
    android:background="@drawable/dual_list_view_footer_next">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oneOfThreeTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="1 of 3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewtextsizeCommon"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/PortscustomviewoneOfThreePaddingTopBottom"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/PortscustomviewoneOfThreePaddingTopBottom" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nextTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/oneOfThreeTextView"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/PortscustomviewnextTextViewPaddingTop"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/PortscustomviewnextTextViewPaddingRight"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/PortscustomviewnextTextViewPaddingLeft"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/PortscustomviewresultsTextViewtextsizeCommon"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteText" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nextImageView"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/oneOfThreeTextView"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PortscustomviewnextImageViewmarginright"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/PortscustomviewnextImageViewmargintop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Since this layout is inflated through LoopbackThroughCustomView.cs class the parent has below xml:

```
<Samsung.Ethernet.AndroidDevice.LoopbackThroughCustomView
    android:id="@+id/loopbackCustomView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/PortsloopbackCustomViewmarginleft"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/PortsloopbackCustomViewmarginright"
    android:layout_below="@id/loopbackplainTxtView" />
```

And the inflate code in LoopbackThroughCustomView.cs class is as:-

```
Inflate(Context, Resource.Layout.loopback_through, this);
```

And the inflate code in Adapter for listview is as:

```
if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new LoopbackThroughViewHolder();
            view = _activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.loopback_through_listitem, parent, false);
            holder.result = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.resultTextView);
            holder.numberofframe = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.numberofframeTextView);
            holder.wrightWrong = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tickCrossImageView);
            holder.linear1 = view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
            view.Tag = holder;
        }
```

And the loopback_through_listitem.axml layout for listitem is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/loopback_through_listview_background">
<View
    android:id="@+id/lineMiddleTextView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/Portscustomviewlinewidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/PortslistitemlineMiddleTextViewheight"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@color/EasyGUIBtnStartColor" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/resultTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lineMiddleTextView"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PortslistitemresultTextViewMarginRight"
    android:textSize="@dimen/PortsEasyGUIBtnTextSize"
    android:textColor="@color/BlackText" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberofframeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lineMiddleTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/PortslistitemresultTextViewMarginRight"
    android:textSize="@dimen/PortsEasyGUIBtnTextSize"
    android:textColor="@color/BlackText" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tickCrossImageView"
    android:src="@drawable/green_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PortslistitemresultTextViewMarginRight" />
```

Now the problem is, when I give divider height to "0dp" in listview in loopback_through.axml, then a small extra space at bottom of listview(betwn listview and relative layout) appears, and when I give divider height as "1dp" then the listview content occupies the bottom space and no space is seen, which is the solution I need. I want to know that why this type of behavior seen in listview is there any other way to occupy bottom space by giving divider height to 0dp by keeping relative layout below listview, I tried giving negative marginTop to relative layout but this is not perfect for all devices.
I would like to eliminate extra bottom space in listview by keeping divider height to 0dp and relative layout to layout_below listview and without giving any top margin or bottom margins. Thankyou.

---

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in your xml code :

```
android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
```

It will remove the last footer divider of your listview which is showing as empty space.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks @Anjali for responding. The property didn't worked. Is this property dependent on any other properties?